# How do i work out this date time issue in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and machine learning and i am trying to work out how to fix this issue with date time. next_unix is 13148730, because that is how many seconds are in five months, which is the time in between my dates. I have searched and i can't seem to find anything that works.

```
last_date = df.iloc[1,0]
last_unix = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-31 00:00:00') +pd.Timedelta(13148730)
five_months = 13148730
next_unix = last_unix + five_months  


for i in forecast_set:
     next_date = Timestamp('2015-06-30 00:00:00')
     next_unix += 13148730
     df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)]+[i]
```

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-18adaa6b781f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HP/Documents/machine learning.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Documents')

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HP/Documents/machine learning.py", line 74, in <module>
    next_unix = last_unix + five_months

  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 1025, in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__add__ (pandas\tslib.c:20118)

ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.
```

Comment: You don't seem to have said what the issue is.

Comment: I am getting this error: ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.

Comment: What is your input, and what output do you expect to print out?

Comment: Last_unix input ('2015-01-31 00:00:00') is the input: the last date before the forecast, and the next_date output('2015-06-30 00:00:00') for the forecast. I am plotting it as a ggplot with the time as the feature (x). It is currently not showing the forecast on the graph, and has a date issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [pd.Timedelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) method:

```
In [20]: pd.to_datetime('2015-01-31 00:00:00') + pd.Timedelta(seconds=13148730)
Out[20]: Timestamp('2015-07-02 04:25:30')
```

if we try to add number of seconds to Pandas DateTime:

```
In [22]: pd.to_datetime('2015-01-31 00:00:00') + 13148730
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c252fc51ec14> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.to_datetime('2015-01-31 00:00:00') + 13148730

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__add__ (pandas\tslib.c:20225)()

ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion,and it is giving me this error: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute timedelta. TIme delta is installed though.

Comment: @Bolajio, there is no `pd.timedelta()`, but there is `pd.Timedelta()` - check my answer ;)

Comment: I made the change it is still giving me the initial error:ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset

Comment: @Bolajio, please post a full error traceback to your question - i'm sure you are still adding integer to pandas.DateTime somewhere in your code

Comment: just add the following line between lines 73 and 74: `print(type(five_months))` - and you'll see that `five_months` is not of `Pandas.Timedelta` dtype - most probably it's an integer

Comment: I took out five_months since it really does not make sense, and the two next_unix . I guess that makes more sense? seems like i have a whole different set of problems now.

Comment: @Bolajio, I think i have answered your question completely - if you want to get rid of `ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.` - you should use `pandas.Timedelta`. I have provided you examples as well. IMO, it should be pretty clear now...

Comment: Yea it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `pd.to_datetime` returns a python `datetime` object, then you should look at using a `timedelta` object for your 5 month interval:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects